# check for duplicate in hash table

Tags: c++, hashtable

I am trying to read a file, each string will be less than 30, and out of the thousands there will be 20 unique sequences. We are counting how many times uniques show up in the hash table. I am having trouble handling collisions. I intialize all char[] values to "0" however if(protiens[key].protien == "0") does not work to check if that spot in the struct has a value of "0" or one of my protiens which are always "ABCDJ..." over 10 and less then 30 chars. So i figured initializing all to "0" would be a way to see if i put a protien in the struct already or not.

This logic error is in my second if statement.

This is the algo we are supposed to use, and then my code.

```
While(there are proteins)
 Read in a protein
 Hash the initial index into the proteins table
 While(forever)
   If(found key in table)
    Increment count
    Break;
   If(found empty spot in table)
    Copy key into table
    Increment count
    Break;
   Increment index; // collision! Try the next spot!

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

//struct to hold data and count
struct arrayelement 
{
  char protien[30] {"0"};
  int count;
};
arrayelement protiens[40];

//hash function A=65 ascii so 65-65=0 lookup table = A=0,B=1... 
//h(key) = ( first_letter_of_key + (2 * last_letter_of_key) ) % 40

int getHashKey(char firstLetter, char lastLetter)
{
   return ((int(firstLetter) - 65) + (2 * (int(lastLetter) - 65))) % 40;
}


int main()
{
   fstream file;
   string filename;
   char word[30];
   int key;

   filename = "proteins.txt";

    //open file
    file.open(filename.c_str());

    //while not eof
    while (file >> word)
    {
       //get key
       key = getHashKey(word[0], word[strlen(word)-1]);

        //loop "forever" no difference if i use 1 or 10000000 besisdes run time????
    for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
    {
        //if found key in table
        if (protiens[key].protien == word)
        {
            protiens[key].count++;
            break;
        }

        //if found empty spot in table
        //if(protiens[key].protien == "0") i intialized all protiens to "0" why would this not work for 
        //checking if i put a protien there already or not
        else
        {
            strcpy_s(protiens[key].protien, word);
            protiens[key].count++;
            break;
        }

        //collison incrment key
        key = getHashKey(word[0], word[strlen(word) - 1]) + 1;

    }

}
//print array of uniques with counts
for (int j = 0; j < 40; j++)
{
    cout << j << "\t" << protiens[j].protien << "\t" << protiens[j].count << endl;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //if(protiens[key].protien == "0") i intialized all protiens to "0" why would this not work for 
    //checking if i put a protien there already or not
```

Since `"0"` is a constant and `protiens[key].protien` is a pointer to a variable, they can't possibly be equal.

Imagine if they were equal. That would mean that `protients[key].protien[0]='Q';` would be precisely the same as `"0"[0]='Q';`. But the former makes perfect sense, changing a variable. And the latter is insane, modifying a constant.

I don't know why you'd use arrays of characters this way when you have `std::string`. But if you insist on it, use `strcmp` to compare strings. Comparing pointers to characters for equality tells you if the two pointers are equal, not if they point to identical strings.

Comment: my teacher hasnt changed his course since 97 so im teaching myself data structures and he said to use a char[], in my previous class we would have used string... I will look into strcmp, and thank you for your explanation of my logic error.